# Why is Boolean complement not the same as integer cancellation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, finite-groups, propositional-calculus

Looking at a computer-science book, I see that `a + -a = 0` (inverse property in integer ring), and that `a & ~a = 0` (Boolean complement).

But these are not given as equivalent (or *shared* properties. But on the face of it, they seem to be.

Why are they not equivalent?

Comment: Well for one thing, the ring of integers behaves much differently than $\mathsf{GF}(2)$.

Comment: $\&$ is almost the same as the product, not the sum.

Comment: Comparing Boolean algebra with the  Galois field of two elements, `AND` is similar to $\times$ while `XOR` is similar to $+$ and `NOT` is similar to additive inverse.     By contrast `OR` has a more complicated interpretation

Answer (score 1):

In set theory, you do not have this.

$$ A - B = A - C \implies B = C;$$
This merely tells you $A\cap B = A\cap C$.  Outside of $A$ it tells you nothing.  The same thing happens in logic.

Comment: I can see how this works in set theory. But I'd like to see it translated to Boolean, because I don't quite see the relationship between the example with set intersections and my question. Maybe this is implying that $\textasciitilde a$, unlike $-a$, can be any value other than $a$.